# remember password in android app

Tags: android

I have developed a login form (username,password and submit button)  using a MySQL connection through soap webservices in my android application.Here I wish to add a "remember password field".
I have written this code in the XML resource for the activity:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AbsoluteLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tf_userName"
    android:layout_width="194dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="106dp"
    android:layout_y="80dp" >

    <requestFocus />
</EditText>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="23dp"
    android:layout_y="93dp"
    android:text="User name" />



<EditText
    android:id="@+id/tf_password"
    android:layout_width="189dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="108dp"
    android:layout_y="161dp"
    android:inputType="textPassword" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="23dp"
    android:layout_y="176dp"
    android:text="Password" />
   <CheckBox android:layout_below="@+id/passwordview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:text="Remember Password!"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/rempasswordcheckbox" 
    android:layout_x="23dp"
    android:layout_y="200dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_login"
    android:layout_width="106dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="50dp"
    android:layout_y="273dp"
    android:text="Login" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/TextView03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="50dp"
    android:layout_y="350dp"
    android:text="Forget My password ?: Click here" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_reg"
    android:layout_width="106dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="175dp"
    android:layout_y="273dp"
    android:text="Register" />
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/btn_logout"
    android:layout_width="106dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_x="215dp"
    android:layout_y="25dp"
    android:text="Logout" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tv_status"
    android:layout_width="151dp"
    android:layout_height="38dp"
    android:layout_x="26dp"
    android:layout_y="234dp"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
```

my Login.java file is:

```
package com.truebranches;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapPrimitive;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Login extends Activity {
private final String NAMESPACE = "http://ws.userlogin.com";
private final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8085/Login/services/Login?wsdl";
private final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://ws.userlogin.com/authentication";
private final String METHOD_NAME = "authentication";
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);
    Button register = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_reg);
    register.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Switching to Register screen
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Register.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    Button logout = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_logout);
    logout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Switching to Register screen
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    TextView forgetpassword = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView03);
    forgetpassword.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Switching to Register screen
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), ForgetPassword.class);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    });
    Button login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_login);
    login.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  public void onClick(View arg0) {
  loginAction();

  }
 });
 }

  private void loginAction(){
  SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

    EditText userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName);
    String user_Name = userName.getText().toString();
    EditText userPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password);
    String user_Password = userPassword.getText().toString();

  //Pass value for userName variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo unameProp =new PropertyInfo();
    unameProp.setName("userName");//Define the variable name in the web service method
    unameProp.setValue(user_Name);//set value for userName variable
    unameProp.setType(String.class);//Define the type of the variable
    request.addProperty(unameProp);//Pass properties to the variable

  //Pass value for Password variable of the web service
    PropertyInfo passwordProp =new PropertyInfo();
    passwordProp.setName("password");
    passwordProp.setValue(user_Password);
    passwordProp.setType(String.class);
    request.addProperty(passwordProp);

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(URL);

    try{
        androidHttpTransport.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
           SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
           String status = response.toString();
           TextView result = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tv_status);
           result.setText(response.toString());

           if(status.equals("Success!"))
            {
               Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this,HomePage.class);
               intent.putExtra("username",userName.getText().toString());
               startActivity(intent);


            }
           else
            {
               Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Login.class);
               startActivity(i);
            }
           }



    catch(Exception e){

    }
   }

   }
```

But how do I create the Java code? I can't seem to be able to do this. Please guide me.

Comment: I think you want to save password on the click of Login Button???

Comment: s i need dis one...how can i do

Answer (score 6, accepted):

EDIT--------------

```
import....
import android.widget.CheckBox;         // <--- Add
import android.content.SharedPreferences;   // <--- Add
import android.widget.EditText; // <--- Add
.
.
.
.
private static final String SPF_NAME = "vidslogin"; //  <--- Add this
private static final String USERNAME = "username";  //  <--- To save username
private static final String PASSWORD = "password";  //  <--- To save password
CheckBox chkRememberMe; //      <--- You even not taken CheckBox, SILLY WORKER
EditText etUserName, etPassword;    //      <--- You even not taken CheckBox,     SILLY WORKER

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    chkRememberMe = (CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.rempasswordcheckbox);  //      <---  Instantiate CheckBox...
    etUserName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_userName); //  <---  Instantiate     EditText...
    etPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tf_password); //  <---  Instantiate EditText...


    //  ADD THIS  TO  READ  SAVED  username & password  NEXT-TIME OPENING Application
    SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SPF_NAME,
            Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    etUserName.setText(loginPreferences.getString(USERNAME, ""));
    etPassword.setText(loginPreferences.getString(PASSWORD, ""));
.
.
.
.
.
.
private void loginAction() {
.
.
.
.
if (status.equals("Success!"))
{
    //   ADD  to save  and  read next time
        String strUserName = etUserName.getText().toString().trim();
        String strPassword = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();
        if (null == strUserName || strUserName.length() == 0)
                    {
            //  showToast("Enter Your Name");
            etUserName.requestFocus();
        } else if (null == strPassword || strPassword.length() == 0)
                    {
                //      showToast("Enter Your Password");
            etPassword.requestFocus();
        } else
                    {
            if (chkRememberMe.isChecked())
                            {
                SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SPF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                loginPreferences.edit().putString(USERNAME, strUserName).putString(PASSWORD, strPassword).commit();
            } else
                            {
                SharedPreferences loginPreferences = getSharedPreferences(SPF_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                loginPreferences.edit().clear().commit();
                            }
//      OVER

    Intent intent = new Intent(Login.this, HomePage.class);
    intent.putExtra("username", userName.getText().toString());
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

---

If YourCheckBox found **isChecked()==true**

at the time of Login button **onClick**

Just save the username and password to **SharedPreference.**

```
Declare PREFRENCES_NAME = "Name You Like"
Save Data:-

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFRENCES_NAME, 0);
settings.edit().putString("name", strName).putString("pwd", strPass).commit();


Retrieve Data:-

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFRENCES_NAME, 0);
String name = settings.getString("name", "");
String password = settings.getString("pwd", "");


Clear Data:-

SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(
PREFRENCES_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
settings.edit().clear().commit();
```

Comment: hi now read my questions.tell me how is checked rememberpassword in above my coding part.

Comment: remembered password means if i enter the username and password then enabled the remember password checkbox means  it is successfully login.then i clicked logout means it is loggedout.but again i open d app means the username and password is displayed on d edittext know...but when i loggedout dis app is loggedout afterthat again i open d app means the username and password are not saved.

Comment: Actually  it is saved. But at the time of starting Application, you are not reading the SharedPreferences SPF_NAME and not filling values in the EditText of UserName and Password.

Comment: Hey, you had not done any research/design. You even hadn't taken your EditText and CheckBox object in your onCreate. You also hadn't search about SharedPreferences, even not my first answer, See there it shows How to read and write values From/to to SharedPreferences. How can you work without simple logic and Research-power?!!!

Answer (score 1):

if the check box is checked while a login

- store the password in [local storage](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)
- retrieve at run time,whenever the login activity is launched

Answer (score 0):

Using [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) is the easiest way to go.

```
SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
editor.putString(PREFERENCE_IDENTIFIER, usersPassword);
editor.commit();
```

Condition

```
if (rememberPasswordCheckbox.isChecked()) {
// save password here
}
```